# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos de una consulta dentro de php?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tengo el ste panorama: Por un lado en mi BD en mysql tengo una tabla llamada "category"

```
CategoryId  UserId  CategoryName    tipo
  73            1   Salario         10
  74            1   Comisiones      10
  75            1   Horas extra     12
  76            1   Bono            10
  77            2   Salario         10
  78            2   Comisiones      10
  79            2   Horas extra     12
  80            2   Bono            10
```

Y en el código tengo esto:

```
      $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "mi_base");

 $query = "select distinct category.CategoryId, category.CategoryName from 
 category where tipo = 10";
 $mResult = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
```

**Acá hago un select del lado del cliente**

```
                     <select name="ecategory" class="form-control">
                                   <?php while($col = 
                                    mysqli_fetch_assoc($mResult )){ ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $col['CategoryId'];?>">
                                   <?php echo $col['CategoryName'];?> 
                      </option>
                                 <?php } ?>
                     </select>
               </div>
```

La pregunta es como puedo hacer para que sólo traiga, ene se select las categorías (CategoryName) que le corresponde a cada Usuario (UserId)? porque ahora me trae todas las categorías en el select, osea repetidas. Gracias!

Comment: como se muestran en tu select  , podrias poner una imagen o algo.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que traiga los valores para un usuario específico? En ese caso sería añadir al where de la consulta que el id sea igual al id del usuario en cuestión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que agrupar el query con GROUP BY:

```
$query = "select distinct category.CategoryId, category.CategoryName from 
 category where tipo = 10 GROUP BY category.CategoryName";
```

Comment: me generó este error en el query: 
[Err] 1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'moneyone.category.CategoryId' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: suprime el category.CategoryId del query: $query = "select category.CategoryName from category where tipo = 10 GROUP BY category.CategoryName";

Comment: que grande! ahora si muchas gracias x tu ayuda!